# Web2py AJAX value

Tags: python, ajax, web2py

I have a list of Projects in my view and I would like to dynamically generate individual pages for each one. 
My view:

```
{{for i in project_list:}} 
<ul>
  <input id="hello" type="hidden" value="{{response.write(i)}}" name="project_Name">
  <li><a onclick="ajax('{{=URL('default', 'view_project')}}', ['project_Name'], 'target');">View Project</a></li>
</ul>
{{pass}}
```

My controller:

```
def view_project():
    print request.vars.project_Name
    return dict(name=request.vars.project_Name)
```

Essentially, I would like to identify each Project by its `project_Name`.

This is the current output from the controller:

```
['Customizable logistical service-desk ', 'Extended contextually-based prod
uctivity ', 'Face-to-face modular circuit ', 'Multi-tiered stable intranet
', 'Quality-focused coherent budgetary management ']
```

Why am I receiving an Array of all project names as output? 
I just want to identify *each* project.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Its not clear to me what are you trying to achieve, can you please, be more explicit about the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Hey! I am trying to pass individual values using AJAX but instead it is passing an array. So instead of `['Customizable logistical service-desk ', 'Extended contextually-based prod
uctivity ', 'Face-to-face modular circuit ', 'Multi-tiered stable intranet
', 'Quality-focused coherent budgetary management ']` I would like just: `Customizable logistical service-desk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web2py ajax function sends to the server the value of the html element with the name attribute passed in the functions second parameter ("project_Name" in your case), but if there are more than one field with the same name, it will send the values of all of them.

So, you are creating with a loop many fields with the same name, and the ajax function is sending all the values to the server.

You can solve the problem appending a count variable to each field name (and its name on his onclick attribute):

```
{{count = 1}}
{{for i in project_list:}} 
<ul>
  <input id="hello" type="hidden" value="{{response.write(i)}}" name="project_Name{{=count}}">
  <li><a onclick="ajax('{{=URL('default', 'view_project')}}', ['project_Name{{=count}}'], 'target');">View Project</a></li>
</ul>
{{count += 1}}
{{pass}}
```

Or use a more clean solution usin the JQuery ajax function

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
ajax('{{=URL('default', 'view_project')}}', ['project_Name'], 'target')
```

You have specified "project_Name" as the form input element from which to extract the value to post. However, there are multiple inputs on the page all with that same name. As a result, the Ajax function serializes all of their values into a single list and posts the whole list.

You could give each input a unique name, but there is a simpler solution. It appears you are using the hidden `input` elements merely to hold values to be sent by the Ajax function. There is no need for that -- instead, you can simply encode the values directly in the Ajax URL. So, get rid of the `input` elements and change your `ajax` call to:

```
ajax('{{=URL('default', 'view_project', vars=dict(project_name=i)}}', [], 'target')
```